# FontIcon f26c is coming like blank box in android

Tags: android, textview, font-awesome

I am using fonticons to set Icons on textview.

```
Typeface fontIcons = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fontIcons/fontawesome-webfont.ttf");

textview.setTypeface(fontIcons);
textview.setText("\uf26c");
```

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/television/

If I am using this `Unicode f26c`, it is coming like blank box and working fine for other `unicodes`. Can you please tell me what can be the issue here?

Thank you so much in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The icon (television) you are using is added in the **v4.4 of font awesome webfont.***

Probably you are using older version of fontawesome-webfont.ttf in your application that does't contain the unicode icon.

**Download the latest v4.5 fontawesome-webfont.ttf from [here](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/master/fonts) and replace your existing one.**

Hopefully this will help.